# Map Annotations on UITableViewController Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using UITableViewController to show Map Annotations on each cell. I'm adding 10 annotations to each cell. I added viewForAnnotation delegate method to add annotations. I want to use two different images for MKAnnotationView. I'm able to add single image for MKAnnotationView but I don't know how to add multiple.

```
// MKAnnotationView delegate method showing required image.

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
             viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
     NSLog(@"view for annotaion");
     MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation
 reuseIdentifier:@"SearchMapTableAnnotation"];
     annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"handyman_ann_green.png"];
     annotationView.enabled = YES;
     annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
     UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
     return annotationView; }

    //CellForRowAtIndexPath method adding annotations to mapView.
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        [mapView addAnnotations:latLongObject]; // latLongObject is NSArray
    }
```

Comment: You mean you have mapview inside tableview cell?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: I'm adding all annotations when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. But I want to update annotations when user scroll down...

Comment: So what exactly problem in updating annotation? It want update or update wrongly? Please add your `cellForRowAtIndexPat‌h` method